# Unable to parse file 'pom.xml'

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, drools

I'm working on a project with java 8 and maven. I need to upgrade the following jars to the latest version possible: drools-api-5.1.0.M1.jar, drools-core-5.1.0.M1.jar, drools-compiler-5.1.0.M1.jar, drools-templates-5.1.0.M1.jar and drools-persistence-jpa-5.1.0.M1.jar. I have upgraded all the jars to 7.74.1.Final version since higher versions requires java 11 or higher. I have the following method:

```
public static KnowledgeBase createKnowledgeBase(String rule) {
    KnowledgeBuilder kBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    Reader rdr = new StringReader(rule);
    kBuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newReaderResource(rdr), ResourceType.DRL);

    if (kBuilder.hasErrors()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(kBuilder.getErrors().toString());
    }
    KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    knowledgeBase.addKnowledgePackages(kBuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    return knowledgeBase;
}
```

But when I run the application and executes the first line I get this error "Unable to instantiate service for class org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService". Then investigating the issue I found out I had to change the method for something like this:

```
public static KieSession createKieSessionFromDRL(String drl) {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        kieFileSystem.write(kieServices.getResources().newByteArrayResource(drl.getBytes())
                .setSourcePath("rule.drl")
                .setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL));

        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();
        if (kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(org.kie.api.builder.Message.Level.ERROR)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Build Errors:\n" + kieBuilder.getResults().toString());
        }

        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieBuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId());

        return kieContainer.newKieSession();
    }
```

Now when I run the application and executes the new method I get this error:

```
Build Errors:
Error Messages:
Message id=1, level=ERROR, path=pom.xml, line=0, column=0
text=maven pom.xml found, but unable to read
Unable to parse File pom.xml
```

This is my pom, I don't know what is wrong with it, I hope you can help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.csatp</groupId>
    <artifactId>tips</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>24.1.2.0</version>
    <description>TIPS application</description>
    <url>http://home/departments/it/projects/iris2/wiki/</url>
    <name>TIPS</name>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>disable-java8-doclint</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>1.8</jdk>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>windows-1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <artifact.env>LOCAL</artifact.env>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>swing-app-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.ea.maven</groupId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <ciManagement>
        <system>TeamCity</system>
        <url>http://build</url>
        <notifiers>
            <notifier>
                <type>mail</type>
                <sendOnError>true</sendOnError>
                <sendOnFailure>true</sendOnFailure>
                <sendOnSuccess>false</sendOnSuccess>
                <sendOnWarning>false</sendOnWarning>
                <configuration>
                    <address>bjs@csatp.com</address>
                </configuration>
            </notifier>
        </notifiers>
    </ciManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
            <name>Aspose Java API</name>
            <url>https://repository.aspose.com/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>tips_schema</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.csatp</groupId>
            <version>2.3.321</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.csatp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tips</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>public-client-msal4j-sample-AD</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>csa-encryption</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.csatp</groupId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>payflow</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.paypal</groupId>
            <version>4.34</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.csatp.util</groupId>
            <version>1.0.29</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>exceptions</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.csatp</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>drools-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>drools-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <version>7.74.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <version>7.74.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <version>7.74.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>drools-templates</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <version>7.74.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.74.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.74.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-server-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.74.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <version>3.1.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <version>3.3.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>ThreeDLookAndFeel</artifactId>
            <groupId>swing.addon.plaf.threeD</groupId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>EaSynthLookAndFeel</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.easynth.lookandfeel</groupId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>TonicLookAndFeel</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.digitprop.tonic</groupId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0-rc1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <version>1.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.pdfview</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfrenderer</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sferyx.administration.editors</groupId>
            <artifactId>HTMLEditorEnterprise</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jortho</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.inet</groupId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.w3c.tidy</groupId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>novaworx</artifactId>
            <groupId>novaworx</groupId>
            <version>0.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
            <version>R8csa1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>sam</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.bushe</groupId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <version>7.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>commons-sanselan</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.lucee</groupId>
            <version>0.97.0.incubator</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <!--<version>1.4.7</version>-->
            <version>1.4.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>      

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ea.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.50.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ea.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>soa-requestentities</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ea.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>soa-framework</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>exceptions</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.csatp</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- end CSA Web Service dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>btm</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.btm</groupId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>csa-jndi</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.csatp</groupId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jemmy</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.netbeans</groupId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csatp.tips</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-new</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.04</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.3-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.rholder</groupId>

            <artifactId>guava-retrying</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.generali.globalassist.platform.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-common-metrics</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.generali.globalassist.platform.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-common-secrets-manager</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.333</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asp</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.333</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>19.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test/unit</testSourceDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>./</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.cfg.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.jpg</include>
                    <include>**/*.png</include>
                    <include>**/*.gif</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.txt</include>
                    <include>**/*.xsd</include>
                    <include>**/*.vm</include>
                    <include>**/*.drl</include>
                    <include>**/*.drt</include>
                    <include>**/*.rf</include>
                    <include>**/*.xls</include>
                    <include>**/*.dat</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.jpg</include>
                    <include>**/*.png</include>
                    <include>**/*.gif</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.txt</include>
                    <include>**/*.xsd</include>
                    <include>**/*.vm</include>
                    <include>**/*.drl</include>
                    <include>**/*.drt</include>
                    <include>**/*.rf</include>
                    <include>**/*.xls</include>
                    <include>**/*.dat</include>
                    <include>**/*.ortho</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>./</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>

            <testResource>
                <directory>test/unit</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.jpg</include>
                    <include>**/*.png</include>
                    <include>**/*.gif</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.txt</include>
                    <include>**/*.xsd</include>
                    <include>**/*.sql</include>
                    <include>**/*.vm</include>
                    <include>**/*.drl</include>
                    <include>**/*.drt</include>
                    <include>**/*.rf</include>
                    <include>**/*.xls</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>windows-1252</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>iris2-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <!--<outputDirectory>${outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>-->
                    <workDirectory>${outputDirectory}/assembly/work
                    </workDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.csatp.app.client.ClientMain</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.csatp.app.client.ClientMain
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <!--<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>-->
                                <siteDirectory>${basedir}/site</siteDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minmemory>128m</minmemory>
                            <maxmemory>1g</maxmemory>
                            <!--<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>-->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xms128m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <flowInitContext>
                        <masterBranchName>master</masterBranchName>
                        <developBranchName>develop</developBranchName>
                        <featureBranchPrefix>feature/</featureBranchPrefix>
                        <releaseBranchPrefix>release/</releaseBranchPrefix>
                        <hotfixBranchPrefix>hotfix/</hotfixBranchPrefix>
                        <versionTagPrefix>version-</versionTagPrefix>
                    </flowInitContext>
                    <noDeploy>false</noDeploy>
                    <squash>false</squash>
                    <scmCommentPrefix>[RELEASE] </scmCommentPrefix>
                    <enableSshAgent>true</enableSshAgent>
                    <pushReleases>true</pushReleases>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>

                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>

                <version>9.0.9</version>

                <executions>

                    <execution>

                        <goals>

                            <goal>check</goal>

                        </goals>

                    </execution>

                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: `line 0, column 0` would be the first character. If it can't read that, I suspect the file is empty. At least when you invoked maven. Which isn't clear how or when you did that.

Comment: Or the `pom.xml` is corrupt, e.g. an invisible zeroth character.  Try copying all but the first few characters into a clean file, and the type the first missing few characters

Comment: Why don't you follow the conventions? And using `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>       <testSourceDirectory>test/unit</testSourceDirectory>`... https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html also using ancient old plugins versions (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) and also using ancient old dependencies... and if you got an error message it would be helpful to post that full output here...

Comment: The spring-security parts are of 2013!!

Comment: I upgraded a Drools 5.0.1 app to 7.24 (or so) five years ago. It's not a drop-in replacement, you're going to be doing a significant amount of rework. That being said, why are you manually creating the KieFileSystem and not just putting your rules in src/main/resources and letting Drools automatically parse your kiebases out of your kmodule.xml ?

Comment: Also your drools-api dependency is still at 5.1.1